# AngularJs .Run not running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I think the module is not running. In my index.js, i have

```
// index.js ---type 1
// .run not working...
var myServiceToRun = require('./myservice.js');
var mod = angular.module('myApp',[]);
mod.run(myServiceToRun);

module.exports = mod;
// result is only printing console 1... mostly because of the require
```

.

```
// index.js --- type 2
// not working too
var myServiceToRun = require('./myservice.js');
var mod = angular.module('myApp',[]);

module.exports = mod;
// result is only printing console 1... mostly because of the require
```

In myservice.js file:

```
// myservice.js -- type 1
// not working
'use strict';
(function() {
    var mod = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    console.log("In my service 1");

    mod.run(function ($rootScope,$http, $state, $window, $location, urlService, $cookies,accountSecurityServices, localStorageService) {
        console.log("In my service 2");
    });
})();
```

It will never make it to the 2nd console log.
I have tried this snippet as well, but it is not working.

```
//myservice.js --- type 2
// not working
console.log("In my service 1");
module.exports = function ($rootScope,$http, $state, $window, $location, urlService, $cookies,accountSecurityServices, localStorageService) {
    console.log("In my service 2");
    // i will put some stateChange/transition here later on...
}}
```

I have also tried taking out the .run in index.js file, but it is not working too.

Apart from that, i tried to remove the dependency on the myservice.js file and hope that it will work, but it doesn't work too...

```
//index.js
// not working too 

var otherService = require('./otherservice.js');

var mod = angular.module('myApp',[]);

mode.factory('otherService',['$http', otherService]);
mod.run(function ($rootScope, $http, $state, $window, $location, urlService, $cookies, localStorageService) {
    console.log("In my service 2");
});

module.exports = mod;
// my other service, is working fine... just that the .run is not running...
```

I believe this should be a pretty simple task, but i just couldn't get it right... Any idea ?

The app other part of the app is working fine, my other controller/services is working, but it never got into the run function... It will always display console 1, which i believe is printed out because of the require statement...

Comment: where are you defining your module ?

Comment: The module is defined in the index.js ? The file code snippet that i am showing. The other two snippet are within a file called myservice.js, that i included them through the 'require' method.

Comment: `myservice.js` does not export anything but you are treating it as if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a syntax error in your run block, and likewise in declaring your module.

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    var mod = angular.module('myApp', []);
    console.log("In my service 1");

    mod.run(function ($rootScope, $http, $state, $window, $location, urlService, $cookies, accountSecurityServices, localStorageService) {
        console.log("In my service 2");
    });
})();
```

You also have another syntax error in your declaration of myServiceToRun

```
var myServiceToRun = require('./myservice.js');
```

Comment: Edited my code above, and its not working. Thanks for pointing out one of the error, but i guess there are other errors within the code...

Comment: @ThinkTank I have edited my answer to also include your require statement.

Comment: Good to highlight another syntax error. But it still couldn't solve the problem. i had tried to move the whole function into the index file as well, and updated the  code above. But even this is not working :/